# Clear Validations error message in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, formgroups

I have a typescript:

```
dataxForm: fromGroup
this.dataxForm = new FormGroup({
'Description':new FormControl(null, Validaros.required};
'Name':new FormControl(null, Validators.required})
```

I have a html:

```
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<form [formGroup]="dataxForm">
<ng-template #editDescription>
<input formControlName = "Description item">
<textarea matInput cdsTextareaAutosize [formControl]="controls.description"></textarea>
<small class="text-danger"  *ngIf=dataxForm.get('Description').invalid || dataxForm.get('Description').touched"> Description is a required field></small>

<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<form [formGroup]="dataxForm">
<ng-template #editDescription>
<input formControlName = "Name">
<textarea matInput cdsTextareaAutosize [formControl]="controls.description"></textarea>
<small class="text-danger"  *ngIf=dataxForm.get('Name').invalid || dataxForm.get('Name').touched"> Name is a required field></small>


<button mat-button [disabled] = "dataxForm.invalid (click)="submitForm">Submit Form</button>
```

> The validation error message shows up properly as soon as I load the page; under the input
> boxes; 1) How to
> remove error message under input as soon as validations requirements
> cleared? 2) How to unfreeze the submit button when all validations
> requirements cleared?

Answer (score 0):

dataxForm.get('Description') and dataxForm.get('Name') are invalid when the component rendered.

try this:

```
<small class="text-danger"  *ngIf="(dataxForm.get('Description').touched || dataxForm.get('Description').dirty) && dataxForm.get('Description').invalid"> Description is a required field></small>
```

Comment: Thank you;this doesn’t not remove the validation error message once i start typing in the input box; do you know how?

Comment: @uniXVanXcel I don't know whether the errors occur because there are too many **typos** in your .html or not. FIRST, in normal, there is only one same named **formGroup** will be defined in .html. SECOND, maybe it's `formControlName="Description"` not `formControlName = "Description item"`. BTW, in HTML, spaces are allowed between attributes and properties, BUT when value is assigned to attribute or property is better to not have spaces between them.

Comment: Button unfreeze issue => `[disabled]="dataxForm.invalid? true : false"` maybe is a better answer for you